# Deallocate memory of Linked list node in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-management, linked-list, singly-linked-list

In the below code snippet, I'am trying to delete the head node.

```
LinkedList.prototype.removeHead = function() {
    if(!this.head) {
        return null;
    }

    let val = this.head.data;

    this.head = this.head.next;

    return val;
};
```

So after calling this function, the head will now point to next element.

**So my question is will the original head still exist in memory space and do we need to explicitly deallocate the node?**

Like in C/C++ we deallocate the dynamically allocated memory of node using,

`free(node);` or `delete node;`

*How to deallocate memory of such deleted nodes and how is memory managed in JavaScript?*

Comment: Are you new to Javascript ? The memory management is all done by the browser via `garbage collection`. There is no such _free(node)_ or such like low level C/C++ languages in Javascript

Comment: @Plotisateur, Yes! I'am new, so how does garbage collector just deallocate memory automatically without calling delete?